# Turning backlight power off

Tags: windows-ce, power-management

I have a Windows CE 5.0 based device. The problem I'm facing is that the Backlight power off settings under "Control Panel\Display" section does not work. The backlight does not turn off no matter what I do in the control panel.

In the registry there's no key/value named : "BKL" but in any sample code and tutorial I've seen before Backlight's device name was "BKL1:".

What's the matter?

Answer (score 1):

The registry settings for backlight are device/manufacturer dependent. For example , for Motorola/Symbol Devices it is HKCU/controlpanel/backlight/batterytimeout . Your best bet is to visit the developer section of the manufacturers website to get documentation on the registry settings.

Comment: isn't it a strange problem? i mean i suppose i'm not a developer, then my device should not be able to auto backlight off!? i think there are some problems with device drivers and/or registry!

Comment: Yes, It is definitely strange.Bad engineering maybe. But from what i remember , if you have the power connected the device shouldn't turn the backlight off.There is also a backlight setting in the control panel.

Comment: yes, there's a backlight setting in control panel, but doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

This worked on a Honeywell device for me.
In the terminal, go to 'Start' > 'Programs' > 'Power Tools' > 'EZConfig Utilities' > 'DeviceConfig'.
Scroll down and select the 'Power Management' > 'Backlight' > 'Battery' folder, which is enabled by default.
Double click on the key that needs to be changed, and change its value.
Press the big "ENT" key on the physic keypad to save the change.
Close the "DeviceConfig.exm" file saving the changes.
Reboot the terminal and see if it works.